# Old Taxonomy Site Column not working correctly for new Language Packs

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a problem, wherein we had a Site Column pointing to a MMS Term which had labels only in English. Language packs were added later. Ideally this site column should be pointing to the right language labels in the corresponding language sites. But it is Not working. It loads only English terms.

Although, a new Site Column gives the right results.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a little ConsoleApplication or PowerShell script which prints out the SPField.SchemaXml property for one broken and one working field. This is essentially an XML document with the definition of all the properties for these fields. Compare the XML documents to each other and see if you can spot any interesting differences in property values. Hopefully you will find which property is different, in which case you could then write some code to fix the definitions of the broken fields.